# When is a fallback font downloaded?

Tags: html, css, font-face

If I set a Google font as a fallback font like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GoogleFont';
    src: url('GoogleFont.ttf');
}

html, body {
    font-family: 'myMainFont', 'GoogleFont';
}
```

Will the Google font only be downloaded to the user's browser if the main font fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No: browser implementation varies so you can't trust that fonts will be ignored (even if they are not needed).**

The client's OS, browser, and version all cause variant performance -- as do other settings browsers may offer. See [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25002273/2456258) about browser compliance for W3's "rule."

Check the resources that get downloaded in your browser [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/6gB74/1/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/4Eq4B/1/) in different browsers to see how fonts are treated.

---

**That being said**, [according to the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) you *can* have the "fallback" behavior you're looking for if you specify multiple files in the`@font-face` `src` attribute:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyFontName;
  src: url("MyMainFont.tff"), url("MyBackupFont.ttf");
}
```

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/jH8T5/1/), if the first file isn't found, then we continue down the `src` list until we find a valid file. Thus, `MyBackupFont.tff` is only downloaded if `MyMainfont.tff` can't be found. You can also specify local files in the `src` by using `local("FontName")`.

---

By the way, [Chris has a great article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) on how to "use [@font-face] responsibly."

Comment: Ok I will read, thx. But he states font-family: 'MyWebFont', **Fallback**, sans-serif; Where is "fallback" set? I can't see how I can use it for my scenario. Can you help? ;)

Comment: Check out le updated answer. : ) He's using "Fallback" as a filler for any *local* file you may want.

Comment: I already have a <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=MyFont" />. Maybe I should change that to be included from the CSS file instead?

Comment: Yuppers -- that's what I'd do. You ***could*** even grab the *.tff or *.woff url in Google's CSS file that you're importing and include it in the `@font-face` `src`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Wasn't me ;) So, I should set the google font in css too (instead of include external css font?), and direct nr. 2 font to the fontface? I'm a bit confused about all this..

Comment: because not all browsers will download a font just because an @font-face is declared.

Comment: Alrighty, let me add a qualifier to appease ye'. :) And @mowgli, check out the example I just added. Does that help?

Comment: CaseyFalk - your edit to say "most browsers" is not only insufficient, but also inaccurate. It appears the behaviour is highly variable for reasons that aren't being explained in either your or my answers.

Comment: @CaseyFalk - see my edited answer to see what the spec says. Browsers that download fonts when they are not required for rendering are **non-comformant**. That's not to say they don't exist, but according to the spec, they should not be.

Comment: And so I would say that the answer, "browser implementation varies," suffices. Good point in referring straight to the W3 docs.

Comment: Now I have messed with it and tested. Combined all font calls into one @font-face. First it checks for locally INSTALLED font (on machine). Then it tries google external font, and lastly it downloads local server font. Seems to be an ok solution, and now I can rest at night :) Thanks

Comment: But I ended up trusting Google instead. Much easier :)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

According to the spec, @font-face fonts should only be downloaded when they are required to render the document: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-loading

> The @font-face rule is designed to allow lazy loading of font
>   resources that are only downloaded when used within a document. A
>   stylesheet can include @font-face rules for a library of fonts of
>   which only a select set are used; user agents must only download those
>   fonts that are referred to within the style rules applicable to a
>   given page. User agents that download all fonts defined in @font-face
>   rules without considering whether those fonts are in fact used within
>   a page are considered non-conformant. In cases where a font might be
>   downloaded in character fallback cases, user agents may download a
>   font if it's contained within the computed value of ‘font-family’ for
>   a given text run.

**NOTE:**
At the time of writing this answer, different versions of browsers on various systems seem to implement this behaviour wildly differently. All we can do is hope that they will eventually conform to the spec.

<strike>Chrome and Firefox (testing others in progress) will only download fonts that are required to render the content that is being displayed, regardless as to what's been specified via @font-face. More importantly, if you specify an @font-face font and then don't use it, e.g.</strike>

```
.css-rule { font-family: Helvetica,'My at-font-face-font',sans-serif; }
```

Then your custom font face **will not** be downloaded because it does not need to be.

To examine what fonts are being download and when, open up your network tab during a page load.

**EDIT**

It appears that the behavior of browsers varies greatly on this issue and I encourage more looking into your individual circumstances.

I can **guarantee** one thing, however, and that is not all fonts are downloaded all the time in all browsers, just because you've declared them via `@font-face`.

Comment: @CaseyFalk - open up your browsers network tab when you load your page and see for yourself.

Comment: Incorrect, @Adam, I just tested this with a JSFiddle and **the font was downloaded even though it wasn't used.** I don't know how exactly you're testing to get this behavior... http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/6gB74/1/

Comment: Can confirm @CaseyFalk's case on Chrome. The rendered font (check `Computed Styles` in dev tools) of the text is `Times New Roman`, but the `Network` tab shows Open Sans being downloaded, and the link for it injected into the result HTML's `<body>`.

Comment: @ajp15243 - not in my version of chrome. The stylesheet gets downloaded, of course, but the font does not.

Comment: @Adam What version are you on? I haven't upgraded to 36 yet, still on 35.0.1916.153. Also I'm on Linux, but I don't think OS would make a difference here.

Comment: Chrome 36 on windows 8. The stylesheet gets downloaded, the font does not. http://adamjenkins.s463.sureserver.com/font.jpg

Comment: @Adam: "The stylesheet gets downloaded, of course, but the font does not." -- **Nope,** here's another example. the font is downloaded even if it is in the same stylesheet. http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/4Eq4B/1/

Comment: @CaseyFalk - I didn't erase any network requests from the image I posted. Nor do I have open sans installed on my system.

Comment: @Adam Interesting, here's my network activity when loading it: https://i.imgur.com/yylDtNZ.png. Looks like there might be a difference between Chrome 35 and 36.

Comment: @CaseyFalk Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @CaseyFalk Firefox 31 and Chrome36  on Windows 8. Neither downloads the font. Which is why I edited my answer to state the the behavior appears to vary greatly and I encourage testing with your network tab open. http://adamjenkins.s463.sureserver.com/font-chrome-firefox.jpg

Comment: @ajp15243: Version 36.0.1985.125m :)

Comment: @CaseyFalk - I'm using the identical version.

Comment: *sigh* Here, let me send you a screenshot, Adam.

Comment: @CaseyFalk - I don't *not* believe you. But instead of letting this thread become a "your-screenshot-versus-my-screenshot", can't we agree that the behaviour is highly variable for reasons that aren't being explained in either of our answers?

Comment: Oh, I totally agree; I'll make the qualifier in my answer stronger. :) It's super weird that they're performing differently. I'm on W7, but I don't think the difference between W7 and W8 would matter.

Comment: The [Font loading guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-face-loading) are terribly written if you ask me, and can probably be blamed for much of the confusion. The way I interpret it is this… If the custom font-family is *not* referred to in the page's CSS, then *none* of its fonts should be downloaded by the browser, period. If the font-family *is* referred to in the CSS, but it's not the first available font in the stack (and this is what the OP was asking about), it still *might* be downloaded, to allow for individual characters that may not be available in the first font.